# Customized Radio Button Input does not work as supposed to, on re-render in react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-typescript

I created a customized radio button with help of `styled-components` and `react-typescript` The [working code is here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-feynman-k3fg8?file=/src/index.tsx). So In this code when I pass explicitly `checked` props to `true`  on my `RadioButton` component, it gives me a checked radio button but when I try to select another `radio button` I need to click it twice to get it selected animation. Meanwhile in `console log` when on the first click it gives the changed value of another `radio button`. but to get the `selected animation` on that radio button I need to click it twice.

For my code, I made the Real `input` element invisible by `opacity` and overlapped with my custom-created `RadioButton`.
It works **fine** when I am not passing `checked` props on the component. It gives an issue when I am passing the `checked` props to component.

I am not sure is it related to my `custom` created `Radiobutton` or its something related to the re-render issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string | number>("first");
  console.log(selectedValue);

  const handleInputChange = (value: string | number): void => {
    setSelectedValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <RadioButton
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        label="first"
        value="first"
        checked={selectedValue === "first"}
      />
      <RadioButton onChange={handleInputChange} label="second" value="second" />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Sarun It works completely fine If Posibble can you explain what is happening on when I pass `true` explicitly why it needs two clicks. I just want to understand why passing `true` needs two clicks and not working on a single click.